# Does Google TCP Load Balancer replicate traffic between all target groups?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

I've configured a TCP Load Balancer in Google Cloud and I can see the option to select more than one single instance group to send traffic.

[image: google cloud select more than one instance group]

What does really Google Cloud does when selecting more than two instance group? It balances the traffic using the sum of all instances on both instance groups? or it balances the load on the first instance group and then balances the load on the second instance group?

I'm more interested in the second aproach, so I would like to know how to get this in Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying it out, I've checked that the load balancer distributes among all instances in all instance groups evenly, ignoring completely the instance group it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

From this concern the traffic routes to the backends that are closest to the user. You may check this information on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp#:%7E:text=External%20TCP%20Proxy%20Load%20Balancing%20lets%20you%20use%20a%20single,a%20global%20load%20balancing%20service.)

Since you mentioned that you are more interested in the second approach, you can check on Session Affinity wherein it allows you to control how the load balancer selects backends. For more information you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity) .